# Pinterest Layout With Angular Material

Tags: html, css, angularjs, layout, material-design

I need the following layout for [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) were the cards are inserted from left to right, wrap at the end of the available width and fill out any vertical space between cards. All cards have the same width, but different height:

[image]

**Is this possible with plain angular and CSS? How?**

---

I tried to accomplish this with `display:flex` but I couldn't get rid of the vertical space:

```
.cards {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[image]

---

I also found a pure CSS solution, which works out the space problem, but has different order and also requires a fixed height:
https://codepen.io/michellebarker/pen/zvxpoG

[image]

---

## Update

**Additional requirements:**

- Responsive layout: Depending on window with, there are fewer or more columns; but they always fill out all available space (adaptive column width, e.g. 100%, 50%, etc)
- The insertion of the cards must work with `ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:order:reverse"`

Comment: Is there a reason why all of the content has to be in a single container? Could you potentially have three (column) containers and insert each card into the cardCount%3 column?

Comment: The reason for one container is that the layout has to be responsive, therefore depending on the current resolution (landscape/portrait/screensize) the layout has a different column count.

Comment: Use [angular-masonry](https://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp), its giving you simple css and html for the display you are looking for (it's even responsive).

[image: screen shot from the page]

Comment: Downvoted it because this example makes you have to spread the content in different columns in advance. It's just a masonry effect but not a real generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with Angular solution at the moment, however if you are able to translate React solution into Angular one following algorithm and code might be helpful.

So in order to generate that layout partition the items into n columns and let the default layout stack them verticaly. Then lay out those columns using flexbox or percentage width.

In order to make the grid responsive subscribe to window resize events and calculate desired column count.
`columnCount = itemWidth => availableWidth => Math.floor(availableWidth / itemWidth)`

Take a look at [working React solution](http://mikelambert.me/react/#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).
Responsive solution is [available here](https://jsfiddle.net/70ke3r35/).

Comment: This sounds very promising - however, it would be great to have the responsive version directly as a plugin - so I don't have to worry about updating/maintaining layout directives...

Answer (score 1):

I create a plunkr so show you the proof of concept for how this can be accomplished.

http://plnkr.co/j5yZQHK3D7l3nPJ8cPlB

You can utilize `layout-wrap` and `flex` in order to accomplish the type of layout you want with essentially no css needed.

```
<div layout="column" layout-wrap>
  <md-card ng-repeat="card in vm.cards | orderBy:'order':!reverse" flex>
    ...
  </md-card>
</div>
```

What this does is adjust your rows so that the content only takes up the space it needs, but every column remains the same size. It's the best of both worlds! Additionally, you can order them in any way needed (also demonstrated in plunkr)

[image: layout-wrap cards]

Comment: When looking at it closely, the order is not quite right. It should go row-wise (left to right) not column-wise (top to bottom). Like you would expect it from `float:left`. Except, they fill out the vertical space. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

I needed the exact same component. But I couldn't find a pure css solution, and `flexbox` orders the cards from top to botton.

There are some AngularJS based options. But since I am using Angular, I couldn't use them.

Because of this, I developed a component which positions elements from left to right. Elements have same width and different height. The component positions each element by calculating x and y coordinates:

https://github.com/kodfarki/ng-pinterest-layout

You may want to try it, even though the component is under development.

Comment: You can clone and then run the project using `ng serve` and view it on `localhost:4200`. There are minor issues with the component. So, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this angular solution on a few projects:

https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Always worked very well and easy to use.

Also have a look at this:
http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started
As it is used as the underlying library in a lot of masonry looks (pinterest look).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the layout properties provided by angular material....

Your container div

```
<div layout="column" layout-wrap layout-align="start space-between">

...inner divs

</div>
```

Docs can be found here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction